# Wired keyboard (A1243) stopped working

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard

My Apple keyboard Model number A1243 stopped working completely. The keyboard is detected under System Information window but the keyboard is not working. Caps lock key light isn't lit either. I tried changing the ports but nothing. I'm on a MBPro 2018 using a USB-C converter to connect my mouse and keyboard. I've a iMac 21' Mid-2011 and its not working there either.

Any help is appreciated.

[image]

Can someone with the similar keyboards verify the readings under keyboard like current required and others?

The keyboard has two USB ports and these ports are still working just fine.

Comment: Get [Key Codes](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/key-codes/id414568915?mt=12) (freeware) & see if it's generating anything at all. I've never known one of these keyboards just die suddenly, even with a cup of coffee in them they usually only lose a few keys, but that's not to say it cannot happen. Have you checked the intermediate cable too; swap for another if you have one.

Comment: Thank you for you time. I installed this freeware but nothing is shows up in the window when typed using this keyboard. And just before it stopped working the "=" key acted like sticky key without me touching the keyboard and then i pressed escape key and it stopped working completely afterwards. I have a iMac 2011 with direct USB ports and its not working there either. Any other suggestions?

Comment: They're not fixable in any real sense, they're glued together & don't really have anything serviceable inside if you manage to prise it apart, so I'd say it's time to find another on eBay. You'll have to pick through all the non-working listings which flood the bottom end of the price range, but you can still find them for $£€ 10 from users who don't know what they're really worth. [They did hit a high of 140 at one point just after they were discontinued, but that's dropped back a long way now] 25-30 would be a realistic dealer price.

Comment: Yeah i checked already and they were mostly around $50-60 but ebay is not available in middle east anyways. And the new ones are  around $200. 

Can you do check the properties under keyboard on your system if you are using similar keyboard?

Comment: There's only one A1243, though available in different languages. It was the best keyboard Apple ever made, that's why it holds its price. The only thing comparable imnsho is the new wireless version, but that has its foibles & is expensive.

Comment: Can't deny its performance. I've been using this same keyboard for 8 years now with different macs and its simply awesome but why it died all of a sudden, I don't get it. And still the keyboard's USB ports are working just fine. May be I'll try to get it repaired before putting it away.

Comment: They're not designed to be repairable, though. They're glued, single PCB inside.

Comment: @Tetsujin Exactly correct. Best keyboard ever. I had one fail a few years ago, and found it irreparable. I then bought several spares, now on the shelf in a plastic bag, waiting just in case.

Comment: @Tetsujin appreciate your time on this post. Just like how it suddenly stopped working yesterday, it started working again now. Don't know what really happened but its working again and thats all i wanted.